# Is Live Video Chat with MSN/Windows possible?

Tags: video, microsoft, instant-messaging, msn

Is this currently possible in either Lucid or Maverick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`telepathy-butterfly`  which is a backend to the default Ubuntu IM client **Empathy** has just received support for the p2pv2 protocol, which will be the only voice/video protocol used by future version versions of the official Windows client. (see [bug report](http://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26849) and [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/much-coverted-msn-voip-support-lands.html))

Whilst these fixes are in the source code, it will take time for a new version of `telepathy-butterfly` to be released, packaged and put in Ubuntu. We are also dependant on the uptake of future versions of the official Windows client (we will be compatible with all future versions, currently in Beta testing). I imagine this will be working in a mainstream way by Ubuntu release 11.04

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work even with this package installed. Is there a tut I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [aMSN](http://www.amsn-project.net/). Its a MSN messenger clone for linux.

Comment: It dropped video support a while ago AFAICS

Comment: http://kakaroto.homelinux.net/2010/03/amsn-0-98-2-to-be-released-without-audiovideo-support/

Comment: i didn't knew it has dropped the audio/video support after the release of 0.98.2 version. but the official site (http://www.amsn-project.net/features.php) still says it has the web cam support.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a native client but [you can through Meebo](http://dontsurfinthenude.blogspot.com/2010/07/msn-video-chat-in-linux.html) (uses Flash).

Comment: The Meebo help page says "Note: If you're chatting with a buddy who is not using Meebo Messenger they will be sent a link asking them to log in through meebo.com. The Video/Audio chat feature cannot connect directly to an IM account not using Meebo Messenger."

Answer (score -1):

Emesene might possibly work?

Comment: Doesn't have video support yet.

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/08/emesene-15-with-webcam-support.html

You may well be right though, that's why I asked as a question :)

Answer (score -1):

emesene is a great msn chatting program and YES it has a video support till now but it makes the program crash most of the time :D .. i read lots of comments that complain about microsoft denying access to its chat servers for other apps than microsoft's messenger

Comment: Emesene no longer has support.